# Disable fpm only for one virtual host

Tags: server, apache2, php, php-fpm

I have three PHP versions on my Ubuntu 22.04 server: 7.4, 8.1 and 8.2
I set the whole system to work with 8.1 as default and I'm using 7.4 and 8.1 in different virtual hosts according to the version required by the platform installed in it.
The settings I use for that are:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

and

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

Now I need to use `php7.4` without fpm only for one virtual host that has Prestashop installed in it, and it gives a lot of problems with an integration of a dropshipping platform.

I looked for it on the whole web and I'm not able to find a solution. It looks like if I want to have different PHP versions on my server I must install the fpm.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default for the Apache from `mpm_event` to `mpm_prefork` and enable `php7.4`. This way, you can use the default for the Prestashop site, while all your other sites can still use PHP FPM.

Remove this from the virtualhost config of the Prestashop site:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

Run these commands:

```
sudo apt install php7.4

sudo a2dismod mpm_event
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
sudo a2enmod php7.4

sudo service apache2 restart
```